tensorflow: Getting CORS errors while calling faceLandmarkDetection createDetector
I am getting CORS errors while calling faceLandmarkDetection createDetector.
Code (adapted for next.js)
  const setupTensorflow = async() => {
    const faceLandmarksDetection = await import('@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection')
    const model = faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedModels.MediaPipeFaceMesh
    const detectorConfig: faceLandmarksDetection.MediaPipeFaceMeshMediaPipeModelConfig = {
      runtime: 'tfjs'
    }

    detector.current = await faceLandmarksDetection.createDetector(model, detectorConfig)
  }

Specific error in console:

Access to fetch at https://www.kaggle.com/models/mediapipe/face-landmarks-detection/frameworks/tfJs/variations/face-mesh/versions/1/model.json?tfjs-format=file&tfhub-redirect=true (redirected from https://tfhub.dev/mediapipe/tfjs-model/face_landmarks_detection/face_mesh/1/model.json?tfjs-format=file) from origin http://localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I see that other demos online use this runtime with no issues, so there must be a way.
How do I force myself through this frustrating CORS error?
EDIT: allowing all headers in the next.js config did NOT solve this problem:
const nextConfig = withSentryConfig({
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        headers: [
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', value: 'true' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', value: '*' }, // replace this your actual origin
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', value: 'GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT' },
          { key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', value: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
})


https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/8188

It appears that there's a snag with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) while attempting to retrieve the model from TensorFlow Hub (tfhub.dev). CORS policies are in place within browsers to thwart potentially harmful scripts from accessing resources across different origins.To circumvent this error, consider these alternate methods:
Proxy Server: Establish a proxy server on your backend to fetch the model from TensorFlow Hub and relay it to your frontend. This approach confines your frontend operations to your own server, bypassing CORS restrictions.

Model Download: Retrieve the model and host it on your own server or cloud storage. By doing so, you eliminate the necessity of fetching the model from TensorFlow Hub, thereby sidestepping CORS hurdles.
